# Slow application on windows xp 500mb ram

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, windows-xp

I made a c# windows form application which requires .NET 4.0. I wrote it under a windows 8 modern notebook and there it works fast. It's not so heavy, it has two threads which read some values from serial devices and save datas or show charts.
But when I run it on an old pc with windows xp, pentium 4 3GHz, 500mb di ram and prehistoric 20 gb hd, it's very slow. The pc has almost nothing installed, so it's not a software problem. It seems the GUI to be terribly heavy. It takes seconds to open and close forms, if you aren't patient you can simply crash it. There is a gif showed in a picture box. On the notebook it blinks every second, on the pc it blink in 4-5 seconds. The same is for a timer updated every second on the notebook and every 3-4 seconds on the pc.
Apparently it doesn't occupy a lot of resources: used ram is 128 mb and cpu is around 4-5%. Do you have any idea on why it is so slow?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen things like this before, where an application runs very fast on my laptop but then it gets out in the field on a user's desktop with an older processor, things really slowed down.

It helps to run the following performance profiler.  You can install it on the desktop without having to install any developer tools.  Take snapshots around the event that is slow, then in the results you will see what methods are slow.  Maybe there is a file access that runs in a loop and you can reduce the access time be loading the item in memory.  Maybe there is a database call that happens more often that it should.  https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/?fromMenu

On another project we found that first chance exceptions where causing slowness on other computers and it helped to run VS on that hardware and monitor the 1st change exceptions.  Also if you have VS on the box you can pause the processing at slow moments, then look at the stacktrace to see where its likely spending most of the processing time.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Your old Pentium 4 machine most likely does not have a dedicated graphics processor which means all the UI work is being done by the processor. 
A Pentium 4 3 GHz processor is dirt slow by any modern standards. In this PassMark CPU benchmark, it scores '358' while high scoring 'low mid range' CPUs score in the 1700 - 1800. 
https://www.cpubenchmark.net/low_end_cpus.html
https://www.cpubenchmark.net/midlow_range_cpus.html

You did not state what processor is in your Windows 8 machine but it is a good chance it has a dedicated graphics processor (even if it is integrated on-chip) and is generally immensely more powerful than your Pentium 4 machine. 
With this being the case it is not surprising the application is running very slow on the old machine compared to your Windows 8 machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to measure. It could be GC, I/O, JIT, whatever...

I would recommend you [PerfView](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567). It's a few megabytes big profiler from MS, it's free and no installation needed, so you can easily run it on customer's PC.